# Iterating through a two dimensional list of objects in Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm trying to make a simple 2D tile-based game in Python 3.35, but I'm having trouble with multidimensional arrays.

I have a 16*10 sized area, which I fill with "floor"-objects and then I try to iterate through the 16*10 area tile by tile calling the draw method for each floor object. This is where I run in to trouble. For the life of mine I can't figure out how to call the object while iterating.

This is how I fill the area with floor:

```
self.tiles = [[],[]]
self.tiles = [[floor() for x in range(self.width)] for x in range(self.height)]
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
for x in range(bar.width):
    for y in range(bar.height):
        bar.tiles[x][y].draw(x,y)
```

I also tried:

```
for x in range(bar.width):
    for y in range(bar.height):
        bar.tiles[0][x][1][y].draw(x,y)
```

The first version tries to iterate through the lists dimensions (for x), and gets out of range after reaching 2.
The second option looked promising, but gives the following error:

> TypeError: 'floor' object does not support indexing

Any help? Thanks.

SOLVED:
okay, the very first line should've been

```
       tiles = [[]]
```

After this the first version works

Comment: What's wrong with version 1?

Comment: In version 2 you try to get the 1 st element of bar.tiles[0][x] which is a floor.

Comment: It could help if you would create a minimal working example which others could test.

Comment: @pal sch 
Sorry I'm not a native English speaker so I don't know if this will make any sense to anyone. Version 1 doesn't work, because instead of placing the x and y as the first and the second index, it takes x as the index of the dimension I want to access, which gives me a out of range error after it goes to two.

Comment: Maybe self.tiles = [[floor() for x in range(self.width)] for y in range(self.height)] instead of self.tiles = [[floor() for x in range(self.width)] for x in range(self.height)] ?